# социальная сеть на asp.NET Core + Angular 8

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, angular2, asp.net-core-mvc

вчера закончил свой первый [тестовый проект](https://github.com/Lucky63/AngularAndCore)

Получил новую тестовую задачу - написать социальную сеть, т.е. систему в которой имеются те же функции что и в соц. сети. Начал составлять план, но впал в ступор, с чего начать... сижу и пялюсь в пустой монитор. Не могли бы накидать сюда этапы написания, опыта в программировании практически нет, прошлый проект занял 3 месяца, изучать программирование начал 9 месяцев назад с нуля. В голове мысли о том, что надо начать с регистрации пользователя, далее после регистрации наладить функцию переписки, но не могу технически сформировать видение структуры проекта(

Comment: Попробуйте начать не со структуры проекта, а выписать (хотя бы вчерне) требования к нему: набор функций, которыми должно обладать Ваше ПО. Потом от них перейдите к тому ,что должно уметь дополнительно ПО, для того, чтобы реализовывать эти требования. И вот от этого уже можно переходить к структуре проекта.

Comment: а почему нет? все сидят и боятся, а вы сядите и напишите. поверьте, чем больше думаете и знаете, тем меньше шансов на успех.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Взял ручку, листок, сейчас попробую набросать, дальше посмотрим что получится:) Могу ли я о результатах писать тут и задавать доп вопросы? Или на данном ресурсе запрещены обширные и большие темы?

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Успех неизбежен, вопрос лишь во времени, а упорство дает свои плоды:) буду как писали выше выносить весь функционал на лист бумаги, дальше посмотрим.

Comment: Отчета о результатах писать не надо, тут просто сайт вопросов и ответов - вы задаете вопрос и получаете ответ. Если у вас возникает другой вопрос - задаете его отдельно, получаете ответ отдельно.

Comment: Вот неплохой курс на эту тему. Он направлен на знакомство с angular, но там идёт создание небольшой социальной сети: https://www.udemy.com/course/build-an-app-with-aspnet-core-and-angular-from-scratch/

Comment: @alladuh 10$ ломят, так не интересно:)

Comment: Не социальная сеть, но очень похоже по базовому функционалу. Хороший поэтапный наглядный пример реализации можно посмотреть [здесь](https://youtu.be/nItgtJwgV4Y?list=PL3_YUnRN3Uhiz2HomrXKcaEW6b3pDhKTX&t=171)

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос слишком общий и каждый предложит свое решение.

Если архитектура гибкая, то ничего не мешает решать задачи в любом(разумном) порядке имея каркас.

Т.е если компоненты работают через интерфейсы, то ничего не мешает сделать реализации -заглушки. Так, например, контроллер авторизации всегда возвращает истину.

Я бы начал с описания интерфейсов:

1. Описываем интерфейсы доступа к данным
2. Описываем сервисы, которые будут дергать шаг 1.
3. Описываем контроллеры и действия, которые будут дергать шаг 2.
4. Заводим где-то конфигурационный файл с autofac и по мере реализации выполняем внедрение зависимостей.

Хотите авторизацию на конец оставить? Пожалуйста, сделайте реализацию, которая всегда возвращает true.

Сегодня у вас настроение с комментариями повозится? Берете и реализуете сервисы, не меняя почти промежуточный код.

А для тестирования функционала бек-энда не обязательно иметь готовый сайт. Можно слать запросы через какой-нибудь PostMan.